# Numbered list followed by code block breaks formatting

Tags: support, markdown

Is it possible to display a numbered list that is followed by a code block? It seems that an answer with [this structure](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198904/100397) breaks the formatting applied via Markdown.

Here is an example to illustrate the point, with the broken formatting:

1. We will have a first point
2. And a second point as an alternative to the first
3. And finally a catch-all in case neither the of the first options apply

   ## !/bin/bash

   #
   echo "I intend that this four-line block should be displayed as code"
   echo "But it isn't."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to indent it with eight spaces instead of four:

1. Numbered list

   ```
   Code block
   Line 2
   ```

Indenting a line right after a list indicated that it's part of that list item. If you make a new, non-indented line after the list, you'll see it's not part of that list:

> 1. Numbered list
>
> Next line

As compared to:

> 1. Numbered list
>
>    Next line (4 space indent)
> 2. Next list item

Four spaces makes that line part of the previous list item. Eight spaces is four spaces to include the line with the preceding list, and four more to make it code

Comment: Thank you. Why?

Comment: @roaima Edited.

Comment: Ah! I'll go and (re-)read the markdown documentation. (Again!)

Comment: @roaima http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#advanced-lists